# Anonymous user has no attribute _meta in custom user model

Tags: django

I've been facing this problem for so long now and I'm done experimenting. I'm a newbie in Django.

I've been using a custom user model but for some reason this Registration form doesn't work properly. I can't login using the method login(), though it'saving the data fine. Also, the login form doesn't allow any other user login other than the superuser.

Here is the error:

```
AttributeError at /register/
'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/register/
Django Version: 2.2.4
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'
Exception Location: C:\Users\hello\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py in inner, line 257
Python Executable:  C:\Users\hello\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.4
```

Traceback:

```
File "C:\Users\hello\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)
File "C:\Users\hello\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "C:\Users\hello\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\hello\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\hello\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  97.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "D:\authen\authentica\views.py" in post
  40.                 login(request, user)
File "C:\Users\hello\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py" in login
  126.     request.session[SESSION_KEY] = user._meta.pk.value_to_string(user)
File "C:\Users\hello\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py" in inner
  257.         return func(self._wrapped, *args)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /register/
Exception Value: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

Here is the code:

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model 
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin

class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True   
    def create_user(self, email, name ,password=None,is_active= True, is_staff=False, is_admin=False):
        if not name:
            raise ValueError("Users must've a name")
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Users must've a email")
        if not password:
            raise ValueError("User must've a password")
        user_obj= self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email) ,
            name= name
        )
        user_obj.set_password(password)    # Change password for the User
        user_obj.staff= is_staff
        user_obj.admin= is_admin
        user_obj.active= is_active
        user_obj.save(using =self._db)
        return user_obj 

    def create_staffuser(self,email, name ,password=None):
        user= self.create_user(
            email,
            name,
            password=password,
            is_staff= True
        )
        return user

    def create_superuser(self,email, name ,password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            name,
            password=password,
        )
        user.staff = True
        user.admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    name    = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email   = models.CharField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    active  = models.BooleanField(default= True)
    staff   = models.BooleanField(default= False)
    admin   = models.BooleanField(default= False)
    timestamp= models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD  ='email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS= []

    objects= CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.email, self.name

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.staff

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        return self.admin

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.active
```

views.py

```
class RegisterView(TemplateView):
    template_name= 'authentica/register.html'
    def get(self, request):
        user= request.user
        if user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            form = RegisterForm()
            return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        if request.POST:
            form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
                password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
                user = authenticate(email=email ,password=password) #django built in authentication
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('home') 
        else:
            form = RegisterForm()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

forms.py

```
class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
password2 = forms.CharField(label='Confirm password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

class Meta:
    model = CustomUser
    fields = ('email', 'name')

# def clean_name(self):
#     name= self.cleaned_data.get('name')
#     qs= CustomUser.objects.get('name')
#     if qs.exists():
#         raise forms.ValidationError('Name is taken')
#     return name

def clean_email(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
    qs = CustomUser.objects.filter(email=email)
    if qs.exists():
        raise forms.ValidationError("email is taken")
    return email

def clean_password2(self):
    # Check that the two password entries match
    password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
    password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
    if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
    return password2
```

Comment: Please show the full error trace.

Comment: Your form should inherit from `django.contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm`. It doesn't save the password right now.

Comment: Why so? I made a custom model so can I not use a custom form?

Comment: I didn't say you can't use a custom form, I said it makes things easier if it inherits from `UserCreationForm`, which itself is a `ModelForm`, because that takes care of correctly saving the user (and makes your code to clean the password2 redundant). Alternatively, look at the `CreateUserForm`'s `save()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not saving the password for the user. Your custom `RegisterForm` is a `ModelForm` for `CustomUser` that only saves the fields `email` and `name`.

So when you `authenticate()` your user, this fails and returns `None`.

Your next step is to `login()` the user, which is `None` and produces the error you see.

Inherit from `django.contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm` instead of `ModelForm`. That will spare you a lot of code (e.g. you don't have to define the `password1` and `password2` fields, nor `clean_password2`) and correctly save your user.

Comment: Can you tell how this is not saving the password? Kindly give a solution for that too if possible. Thanks :(

Comment: By the way, you're right. It isn't saving the password. I didn't notice that before, saw it in the admin to confirm.

Comment: The answer I gave you tells you how to save the password: inherit from `UserCreationForm` instead of `ModelForm`